# How to add new panels in Dashboard to display user-entry forms?

Tags: openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

I am trying to add a custom dashboard in open-stack-dashboard which will have panels displaying forms accepting the user-data . Where to create and define my models.py into for panels as the settings.py of dashboard doesnt contain any db configurations ?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT : I would recommend not attaching a database directly if you are using Liberty release or later. Make your own rest API externally (easily done with django-rest-framework) and fetch data using angularjs. That is the new standard way in Horizon.**

Horizon does not have a database. It only relies on API calls to keystone and whatever APIs are exposed in the service catalog. If you want to store your own models, you can configure up a database the standard way in any django application.

Add db info in openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py so you don't tamper with the default settings.

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [...]
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'mydb1': { ... },
    'mydb2': { ... },
}
```

This is assuming you actually have to store custom data. I would guess that it's pretty normal to hook up databases or APIs for additional customer information.  registration process, billing info and other custom stuff.

Also make sure you create your custom stuff outside the source tree an hook it up in openstack_dashboard/local/enabled. This makes it cleaner in the future when upgrading the horizon source.

Example :

```
openstack_dashboard
├── ....
horizon
├── ...
mystuff
├── horizon
│   ├── mydashboard
│   │   ├── panel1
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── panel.py
│   │   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   │   ├── views.py
│   │   ├── panel2
│   │   │   ├── ....
│   │   ├── dashboard.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py (Unless defined elsewhere)
│   │   ├── static
│   │   └── templates
```

Then import the dashboard package in openstack_dashboard/local/enabled/_50_mydashboard.py

```
# The name of the dashboard to be added to HORIZON['dashboards']. Required.
DASHBOARD = 'mydashboard'
# If set to True, this dashboard will be set as the default dashboard when the user logs in
DEFAULT = False
# If set to True, this dashboard will not be added to the settings.
DISABLED = False
# A dictionary of exception classes to be added to HORIZON['exceptions'].
#ADD_EXCEPTIONS = {}
# A list of applications to be added to INSTALLED_APPS.
ADD_INSTALLED_APPS = ['mystuff.horizon.mydashboard']
```

For dashboard and panel setup :
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/topics/tutorial.html

Custom stable theme :
http://www.matthias-runge.de/custom-theme-for-horizon.html

Comment: I have added a custom dashboard in my openstack-dashboards/openstack_dashboard/dashboards dir and added the _50_dashboard.py also with all the changes in the local/setiings.py file, but still no changes are being shown up and  I get a **500** server response (error). Is it because I have'nt added any **templates** and **static** directory in my custom dashboard dir ?

Comment: There must certainly be a stack trace somewhere with information about that went wrong? Is this on server startup or when you try to access a certain URL? The template directory is automatically added to TEMPLATE_DIRS, so not sure if that is a problem.

Comment: Might also be good to know what version you are using. I assume its Icehouse or whatever is in trunk now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ..! I got the custom dashboard, specified the urls.py file for the panel which was causing the issue as it was'nt able to redirect to a view.